# nouns to introduce the subjunctive mode (?)

Tags: grammar

Is it possible to introduce/form the subjunctive mode with a noun?
Are all the sentences below formed correctly?

eg

Mike recommended that Suzy not be at the meeting - ok

recommendation that Suzy not be at the meeting - ok??

He suggested that I leave immediately - ok

suggestion that I leave immediately - ok??

etc

Comment: Yes, they're all correct (though they're not all sentences, of course). In general, a noun formed from a complement-taking verb inherits the same set of options, affordances, and prohibitions for complement clauses that the verb displays, including the ability to take an untensed _that_-clause complement like _that she leave immediately_.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong (or even, *unusual*) with *The board approved his **recommendation that Suzy not be at the meeting***. What makes you question the usage?

Comment: Nor anything wrong with *There was a **suggestion that I leave immediately.***

Comment: They are all okay. But note that 'subjunctive' is not a mood, though traditional grammar calls it that. It's best described as a type of clause construction headed by a plain form verb. The subordinate clauses in your examples are all subjunctive mandatives with a declarative content clause as complement.